# How to run new JSF full crude application created by app builder in Sakai

Tags: jsf, tomcat, sakai

I have Sakai 2.8.1 source code and creating full crude application (JSF) and it deployed successfully on a Tomcat 5.1 server, however at run time it shows this error.

```
org.sakaiproject.portal.api.PortalHandlerException: org.sakaiproject.tool.api.ToolException: Could not get property value of component items:_idJsp6
    at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.SkinnableCharonPortal.doGet(SkinnableCharonPortal.java:862)
caused by: org.sakaiproject.tool.api.ToolException: Could not get property value of component items:_idJsp6
    at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.SkinnableCharonPortal.forwardTool(SkinnableCharonPortal.java:1429)
caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not get property value of component items:_idJsp6
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Could not get property value of component items:_idJsp6
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:211)
caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Could not get property value of component items:_idJsp6
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Could not get property value of component items:_idJsp6
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.get(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:235)
caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sakaiproject/submativeassessment/logic/ExternalLogic
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sakaiproject.submativeassessment.logic.ExternalLogic
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at java.beans.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:1272)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1270)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1136)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:387)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:159)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyResolverImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getType(PropertyResolverImpl.java:325)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.initializeProperties(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:314)
    at org.sakaiproject.jsf.app.SakaiVariableResolver.resolveVariable(SakaiVariableResolver.java:76)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl$ELVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ValueBindingImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.commons.el.NamedValue.evaluate(NamedValue.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ExpressionString.evaluate(ExpressionString.java:114)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:386)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.getComponentProperty(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:387)
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentAttributesMap.get(_ComponentAttributesMap.java:235)
    at org.sakaiproject.jsf.util.RendererUtil.getAttribute(RendererUtil.java:88)
    at org.sakaiproject.jsf.renderer.InstructionMessageRenderer.encodeEnd(InstructionMessageRenderer.java:59)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:539)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.encodeEnd(UIComponentTag.java:498)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.doEndTag(UIComponentTag.java:366)
    at org.apache.jsp.submativeassessment.SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp._jspx_meth_sakai_005finstruction_005fmessage_005f0(SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp.java:419)
    at org.apache.jsp.submativeassessment.SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f1(SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp.java:350)
    at org.apache.jsp.submativeassessment.SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp._jspx_meth_sakai_005fview_005fcontent_005f0(SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp.java:314)
    at org.apache.jsp.submativeassessment.SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp._jspx_meth_sakai_005fview_005fcontainer_005f0(SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp.java:217)
    at org.apache.jsp.submativeassessment.SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.submativeassessment.SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp._jspService(SubmativeassessmentItems_jsp.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:419)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:211)
    at org.sakaiproject.jsf.app.SakaiViewHandler.renderView(SakaiViewHandler.java:137)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:598)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.sakaiproject.jsf.util.JsfTool.dispatch(JsfTool.java:221)
    at org.sakaiproject.jsf.util.JsfTool.doGet(JsfTool.java:241)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.sakaiproject.tool.impl.ActiveToolComponent$MyActiveTool.forward(ActiveToolComponent.java:511)
    at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.SkinnableCharonPortal.forwardTool(SkinnableCharonPortal.java:1429)
    at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.handlers.ToolHandler.doTool(ToolHandler.java:204)
    at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.handlers.ToolHandler.doGet(ToolHandler.java:96)
    at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.SkinnableCharonPortal.doGet(SkinnableCharonPortal.java:862)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:843)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can you please post your JSF page and the Managed Bean?  It looks like your page is referencing a managed bean property that doesn't exist.  Without seeing your code there is nothing more I can tell.  Also, what is Sakai? I have never heard of this.

Comment: @maple: that's an old Chinese JSF 1.x implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The App Builder is broken for JSF apps. It is not recommended to be used for current projects since it hasn't been updated since Sakai 2.6 era.

It is also not recommended to use JSF for new Sakai applications.

Try the [programmer manual](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Sakai+Programmer+Manual):

And for new apps, either the [Apache Wicket](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Sakai+Wicket+Maven+Archetype) or [Spring MVC Maven archetypes](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Sakai+Spring+MVC+Maven+Archetype)